# How to Load Different Javascript(ads) after page reload?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need a help. I want to show different ads after the page reloads in the same positions. Suppose, I put the mellowads javascript code in the header leaderboard. Now I want to load coinads after page reload.

I used This code for random image with link after reload. Now I want to load different javascript(ads) after page reload.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var total_images = 3;
var random_number = Math.floor((Math.random()*total_images));
var random_img = new Array();
random_img[0] = '<a href=""><img src=""><\/a>';
random_img[1] = '<a href=""><img src=""><\/a>';
random_img[2] = '<a href=""><img src=""><\/a>';
document.write(random_img[random_number]);
--></script>
```

Comment: Please update your question to include the HTML for your page as well as any libraries you're using.

Comment: May I presume your JS ads are external scripts? If so, look for dynamic inlcude of JS and include the one needed by branching with a condition.

Answer (score 0):

create a var with local storage with you ads javascript information

then when you reload you can make an simple if with the var content 
to insert in the place of your want on DOM.

```
localStorage.setItem('mySavedJsAds ', 'mellowads ');
```

Then you only get when you want the information about the ads showing.

Comment: hi  @MDAbdullah, i'm glad to help you, but you can make any jsfiddle please for put the content using this.

Comment: basically you have a value stored in you session in that you can set it with the value of you showings ads. If you have any change in your page like reload; you only have to do is change the value of local storage variable. to `localStorage.setItem('mySavedJsAds ', 'myNewsOfTechnologies');` set.

Comment: This is the a-ads 728*90 Banner <iframe data-aa='967545' src='//ad.a-ads.com/967545?size=728x90' scrolling='no' style='width:728px; height:90px; border:0px; padding:0;overflow:hidden' allowtransparency='true'></iframe> and  this is the bitmedia 728*90 banner <ins class="bmadblock-5bc2f878dca8330010de78d1" style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px;"></ins>
<script async type="application/javascript" src="//ad.bitmedia.io/js/adbybm.js/5bc2f878dca8330010de78d1"></script>  please write the code for this